# how to capture all data from spreadsheet to google form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

here's my code and i already input loop command but it only can capture the first row from spreadsheet to google form response.
i need to capture all data from spreadsheet when i execute the code.
anyone know what im missing ?

```
function auto_data() {


  var formURL="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSec8kePcCeGY0vlq3FdIepQgE84Wh7DiYE1e0v7ZWvo5XhxoQ/formResponse";

  var wrkBK = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var wrkSht= wrkBK.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  for (var i=2;i<=5;i++){

  var a = wrkSht.getRange('A'+i).getDisplayValue();
  var b = wrkSht.getRange('B'+i).getDisplayValue();
  var c = wrkSht.getRange('C'+i).getDisplayValue();

  }

  var datamap = {"entry.1436037797":a,
  "entry.995641845":b,
  "entry.1420146463":c};

  var options = {
    "method":"post",
    "payload": datamap };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(formURL, options);
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting what you're trying to do. Do you want to pass data from Spreadsheet to Google Forms to build answers or questions in your form? have you heard about the [FormApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app)
I think it would be a better approach to what you're requering.

Comment: Im trying to pass my data to my existed form, i manage to do 1 row data but idk how to pass all my data to form

Comment: I could manually copy paste the code and edit the range but im doing it for 400+ data, it would takes too much time

Comment: https://youtu.be/6S6ib0dv0qk in this video intro is what im trying to do, import multiple data at once, but in the video only showed how to import single row only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move your `fetch(..)` call and payload composition into the `for` loop:

```
function auto_data() {


  var formURL="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSec8kePcCeGY0vlq3FdIepQgE84Wh7DiYE1e0v7ZWvo5XhxoQ/formResponse";

  var wrkBK = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var wrkSht= wrkBK.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  for (var i=2;i<=5;i++){

    var a = wrkSht.getRange('A'+i).getDisplayValue();
    var b = wrkSht.getRange('B'+i).getDisplayValue();
    var c = wrkSht.getRange('C'+i).getDisplayValue();
    var datamap = {"entry.1436037797":a,
    "entry.995641845":b,
    "entry.1420146463":c};

    var options = {
      "method":"post",
      "payload": datamap };

    UrlFetchApp.fetch(formURL, options);
  }
}
```